# SQL select rows while ignoring duplicate set of columns

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I have these two tables

```
Shoe 

id: str
size: str
model_id: str
created_at: Date
```

```
Model

id: str
name: str
```

I want to query join Shoe and Model ordered by created_at.
So I have this query

```
Select * 
from Shoe 
  join Model on Shoe.model_id = Model.id 
ordered by Shoe.created_at DESC 
limit 10
```

But the caveat is that I do not want to rows with the same size and model_id in this result.

For example

| id | size | model_id | created_at | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | abc | 2022-12-06 | 'Shoe' |
| 2 | 10 | abc | 2022-12-04 | 'Shoe' |
| 3 | 11 | abc | 2022-12-03 | 'Shoe' |

In the above example, I only want first one and third one. Second one has the same size + model_id as the first one so we ignore.

How can we achieve this?

I have been trying to play with group_by, but still can't seem to figure this out

How can I modify this SQL command

```
Select * 
from Shoe 
  join Model on Shoe.model_id = Model.id 
ordered by Shoe.created_at DESC
limit 10
```

to get the desirable result?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: The correct syntax in SQL is `order by` not `ordered by`

Answer (score 0):

This could be one way of doing it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Shoe 
 join Model on Shoe.model_id = Model.id 
 JOIN (SELECT [size], [model_id], MIN([id]) AS "Min Id" FROM Shoe GROUP BY [size], [model_id]
) as f1 ON f1.[size] = Shoe.[Size] AND f1.[model_id] = Shoe.[model_id] AND f1.[Min Id] = Shoe.[Id]
order by Shoe.created_at DESC 
limit 10
```